# Should I use SSR?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm planning on building a web app similar to omegle.com using React.

I'm wondering if SSR done using Next.js is the right choice as the app is pretty content light and the most of content is just the user camera. I need good SEO bu I never used Next.js and it might be just additional overhead. I'll be using Twilio API for room creation, chat etc.

So what option should I go for and why?

1. SSR Using Next.js
2. CSR using React.js
3. Make a welcome page using Next and redirect to app.domain.com which uses CSR React.js?

Or do you know something better I should do?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends really on the scale and type of your application But generally speaking you should go with SSR because of how incredibly fast it is. This means your site gets better indexed by google and other search engines and hence giving you an edge in terms of visibility etc. [Refer to this article for more in depth discussion.](https://codeburst.io/next-js-ssr-vs-create-react-app-csr-7452f71599f6)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know about advantages of SSR over CSR but still not sure if using SSR is worth using when app is not content heavy, no images to load, no text. Really the app is just camera video from API and a few buttons.

Comment: well for that as i said it depends so if its not that heavy then sure go with a CSR approach but the reason i would still recommend SSR is that you aren't gonna stop with just this one app? obviously there will be different projects so why not get a feel for SSR on a smaller scale so that you could move on to bigger projects confident. Plus there is no down side to using SSR on smaller apps.

Comment: PS dont go with option number 3 that you listed its not very good

Comment: if it helped you out can you please consider accepting the answer?